# How to profiling layer-by-layer in Pytroch?

Tags: profiling, pytorch

I have tried to profile layer-by-layer of DenseNet in Pytorch as caffe-time tool.

First trial : using autograd.profiler like below

```
...
model = models.__dict__['densenet121'](pretrained=True)
model.to(device)

with torch.autograd.profiler.profile(use_cuda=True) as prof:
    model.eval()
print(prof)
...
```

But the any results are shown except for this message :

```
<unfinished torch.autograd.profile>
```

Ultimately, I want to profile network archtiectures(i.g.DenseNet) to check where bottlenecks happen.

Could anyone do this?

Comment: Do you want to use `use_cuda = True` ? As it add 4us overhead for each tensor operation and which version of pytorch are you using ?

Comment: @papabiceps Yes, I want GPU profiling using TITAN X. Pytorch verision 1.0.

Comment: `model.eval()` does not perform any computation - it only changes the "state" of the model from "training" to evaluation. This "state" affect the behavior of layers such as BatchNorm and DropOut

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To run profiler you have do some operations, you have to input some tensor into your model.

Change your code as following.

```
import torch
import torchvision.models as models

model = models.densenet121(pretrained=True)
x = torch.randn((1, 3, 224, 224), requires_grad=True)

with torch.autograd.profiler.profile(use_cuda=True) as prof:
    model(x)
print(prof)
```

This is the sample of the output I got:

```
-----------------------------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------
Name                                        CPU time        CUDA time            Calls        CPU total       CUDA total
-----------------------------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------
conv2d                                    9976.544us       9972.736us                1       9976.544us       9972.736us
convolution                               9958.778us       9958.400us                1       9958.778us       9958.400us
_convolution                              9946.712us       9947.136us                1       9946.712us       9947.136us
contiguous                                   6.692us          6.976us                1          6.692us          6.976us
empty                                       11.927us         12.032us                1         11.927us         12.032us
mkldnn_convolution                        9880.452us       9889.792us                1       9880.452us       9889.792us
batch_norm                                1214.791us       1213.440us                1       1214.791us       1213.440us
native_batch_norm                         1190.496us       1193.056us                1       1190.496us       1193.056us
threshold_                                 158.258us        159.584us                1        158.258us        159.584us
max_pool2d_with_indices                  28837.682us      28836.834us                1      28837.682us      28836.834us
max_pool2d_with_indices_forward          28813.804us      28822.530us                1      28813.804us      28822.530us
batch_norm                                1780.373us       1778.690us                1       1780.373us       1778.690us
native_batch_norm                         1756.774us       1759.327us                1       1756.774us       1759.327us
threshold_                                  64.665us         66.368us                1         64.665us         66.368us
conv2d                                    6103.544us       6102.142us                1       6103.544us       6102.142us
convolution                               6089.946us       6089.600us                1       6089.946us       6089.600us
_convolution                              6076.506us       6076.416us                1       6076.506us       6076.416us
contiguous                                   7.306us          7.938us                1          7.306us          7.938us
empty                                        9.037us          8.194us                1          9.037us          8.194us
mkldnn_convolution                        6015.653us       6021.408us                1       6015.653us       6021.408us
batch_norm                                 700.129us        699.394us                1        700.129us        699.394us
```

There are many rows below this.

I have used (1,3,224,224) tensor as densenet only accepts 224x224 images. In the future change tensor size according to the network.

Comment: You can also export the profiling to a trace timeline using `prof.export_chrome_trace(path)`, you can then open the trace timeline in chrome://tracing.